# How to reflect nullable fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I want to check if my field is assignable from a type. In my class which I am reflecting some fields are nullable (let's say `String?`) but when I check it by reflection:

```
if(field.type.isAssignableFrom(String::class.java)) {...}
```

this is always false. Is it possible to reflect nullable fields in Kotlin?

Comment: 1. What is the type of `field`? 2. What do you get if you print `field.type`?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the `field` type is a nullable type, e.g. `String?`. When I print `field.type` I get: `class java.lang.String` that is why I found it confusing

Comment: No, I mean the type of the variable `field` itself (probably `java.lang.reflect.Field` but it isn't clear)

Comment: yeah, it is indeed `java.lang.reflect.Field`

Comment: Then yes, something strange is happening. Sometimes `Class` comparison can fail because they have different classloaders, but for `String` I would be surprised (if it's even allowed to be loaded by non-system classloaders). I just verified that `class HasNullableField(val fld: String?); println(HasNullableField::class.java.getDeclaredField("fld").type.isAssignableFrom(String::class.java))` prints true, so a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: well, it happens for other types too, `Boolean?`, `Double?` etc

Comment: `Boolean?` and `Double?` are quite different because they correspond to primitives. If your problem actually happens with them and not `String?`, I can answer.

Comment: Please, do so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> well, it happens for other types too, Boolean?, Double? etc

As described in [the Kotlin documentation on basic types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation):

> On the Java platform, numbers are physically stored as JVM primitive types, **unless we need a nullable number reference (e.g. Int?)** or generics are involved. In the latter cases numbers are boxed.

So `field.type` for a `Boolean?` is `java.lang.Boolean`, but `Boolean::class.java` is the primitive `boolean` type. Use `java.lang.Boolean::class.java` or [`Boolean::class.javaObjectType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) and the comparison will succeed (but fail for non-nullable `Boolean` fields!). The same applies to number types and `Char`.

Comment: Great answer. What About `Int?` though?

Comment: `Int?` is even mentioned in the quote (the wrapper class is `java.lang.Integer`), the full list is in the link.

Comment: ah, the wrapped class name is different, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! The implementation I came up with is:

```
    fun isFieldOfClassNullable(property: KMutableProperty1<*, *>, comparedClass: KClass<*>): Boolean {
    val comparedReturnType = comparedClass.createType()
    return property.returnType.isSupertypeOf(comparedReturnType)
}
```